# Why am I getting this traceback error for Driver and how can I improve the code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

From this other question ([Methods to webscrape Prizepicks for all NBA props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155460/methods-to-webscrape-prizepicks-for-all-nba-props/77334893#77334893)), I'm using the code provided but I am getting this traceback of "driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/") NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?" on line 9, any idea why I'm getting this? Thanks in advance! Below is the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "close").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='name'][normalize-space()='NBA']").click()
time.sleep(2)

# Wait for the stat-container element to be present and visible
stat_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "stat-container")))

# Find all stat elements within the stat-container
# i.e. categories is the list ['Points','Rebounds',...,'Turnovers']
categories = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".stat-container").text.split('\n')

# Initialize empty list to store data
nbaPlayers = []

# Iterate over each stat element
for category in categories:
    # Click the stat element
    line = '-'*len(category)
    print(line + '\n' + category + '\n' + line)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[text()='{category}']").click()

    projections = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".projection")))

    for projection in projections:

        names = projection.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="name"]').text
        points= projection.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="presale-score"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        text = projection.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="text"]').text.replace('\n','')
        print(names, points, text)

        players = {'Name': names, 'Prop':points, 'Line':text}

        nbaPlayers.append(players)

pd.DataFrame(nbaPlayers)
```

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: When you call `driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/")`, the variable `driver` does not exist.  What were you expecting it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameError in Python means that when you attempt to access an identifier that has not been defined within the current local or global scope.

In that case, **NameError: name 'driver' is not defined**. It means that Python doesn't recognize the variable 'driver' because it hasn't been defined in your code before.

So, to solve this issue. You have to define the variable before driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/"):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='') # Provide the path to your ChromeDriver executable
```

Or you can use code below to more readable

```
path = '' # Provide the path to your ChromeDriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

For more information about WebDriver:

- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-nameerror-exception-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for the help and the explanation! I appreciate it!